# I am trying to upload an image using ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC

Tags: image, upload, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to upload and save an image using ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC and am having some issues. I can get the image to upload but it will not save to the database. I have been looking at other examples but am struggling with getting it to do what I want it to do. I am still new to programming in ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC, so I might be just over looking something.

I am hopping someone out there with a much bigger brain then mine can help me out and show me where I have gone wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Controller: `EmployeeControler`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync([Bind] Employee employee, IFormFile EmployeeImage)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            objemployee.AddEmployee(employee);
        }

        if (EmployeeImage != null && EmployeeImage.Length > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(EmployeeImage.FileName);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\Images", fileName);

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {    
                await EmployeeImage.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        return View(employee);
}
```

Model: `EmployeeDataAccessLayer`:

```
// To add new employee record    
public void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Add_Worker", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeNumber", employee.EmployeeNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PositionTitle", employee.PositionTitle);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", employee.FirstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", employee.LastName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dept", employee.Dept);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HireDate", employee.HireDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeImage", employee.EmployeeImage);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Model `Employee`:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Clock Number is required")]
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Position Title is required")]
    public string PositionTitle { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Department is required")]
    public string Dept { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Hire Date is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose file to upload.")]
    public string EmployeeImage { get; set; }
}
```

View `Create`:

```
@model Flexfab.Models.Employee
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
<h4>Employees</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Clock Number:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Clock Number" })
                <span asp-validation-for="EmployeeNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Position:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PositionTitle, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Position Title" })
                <span asp-validation-for="PositionTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "First Name" })
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Last Name" })
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Dept:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Dept, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Dept" })
                <span asp-validation-for="Dept" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Hire Date:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HireDate, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "mm/dd/yyyy" })
                <span asp-validation-for="HireDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Employee Picture:</label>
                <br />
                <input type="file" id="EmployeeImage" name="EmployeeImage">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeImage, new { @class = "form-control" })
                <span asp-validation-for="EmployeeImage" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save images or other types of files in database, but instead you will be able the save only the path of the file. The image would be saved in the folder `wwwroot\Images`. To retrieve the file you need first to save that file.

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{    
     await EmployeeImage.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
     employee.EmloyeeImage = fileName.Uri.OriginalString;
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```